# computing Average of ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double> in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a concurrent linked queue defined as below, what's the right way to get the average of all the elements in java 8 using streams.

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double> cpu = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Double>();
```

Thanks

Comment: How do streams enter into this?

Comment: I'd say do whatever you would do for any other collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
cpu.stream().mapToDouble(a -> a).average().getAsDouble();
```

Comment: +1. A little explanation which you lack: a `Stream` is a sequence of general objects. The average has only meaning in case of numbers. So since your stream is created from a list of doubles, the stream will produce `Double`s so you can convert it to a `DoubleStream` with a straight `a -> a` mapping. `DoubleStream` provides methods which are meaningful and are applied on numbers including `average()`.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `Double::doubleValue` instead of `a -> a` to make it more explicit.

Comment: Keep in mind that this operation relies on the queue’s [*weakly consistent*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly) spliterator and may or may not reflect concurrent modifications or reflect only some of them. Unless you can preclude concurrent modifications while this operation is ongoing, it might result in an average value that never existed at any point of time.